# useCapture in addEventListener behaves strangely

Tags: javascript, dom-events, addeventlistener

I'm trying to make sense of the `useCapture` parameter in JavaScript's `addEventListener()`. Here's my HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <button id="button">Click me</button>
</div>
```

Here's my JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('wrapper').addEventListener('click', function () { console.log('Wrapper capture'); }, true);
document.getElementById('wrapper').addEventListener('click', function () { console.log('Wrapper bubble'); }, false);
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function () { console.log('Button bubble'); }, false);
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function () { console.log('Button capture'); }, true);
```

Now, I expected the order to be `Wrapper capture, Button capture, Button bubble, Button bubble`. Surprisingly, here's my output:

```
Wrapper capture
Button bubble
Button capture
Wrapper bubble
```

The two button handlers are getting mixed up? I tested it in other browsers, but Chrome, Firefox and IE10 all display the same behavior. I'm a bit baffled by this. [The MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/EventTarget.addEventListener), [QuirksMode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html) and [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/NOTE-DOM-Level-3-Events-20031107/events.html#Events-EventTarget-addEventListener) all clearly describe the different phases and how the capture phase precedes the bubbling phase. How come my little experiment results in the `Button bubble` handler getting called before my `Button capture`?

Here's a Fiddle of what's going on: http://jsfiddle.net/Tr7G6/2

---

**// Update** 
It seems the order of attaching the handlers matter.

```
document.getElementById('wrapper').addEventListener('click', function () { console.log('Wrapper capture'); }, true);
document.getElementById('wrapper').addEventListener('click', function () { console.log('Wrapper bubble'); }, false);
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function () { console.log('Button capture'); }, true);
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function () { console.log('Button bubble'); }, false);
```

Binding to capture first and bubble second does produce the output I expected, cross-browser. But this is silly. Why does this order matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bubbling/capturing  only relevant when an event bubbles/captures to a target element, not when the event is triggered directly on that element (this is the "target phase" of W3C events model). In the case that there is no "bubble" or "capture" — which is the case with the `click` event on your `<button>` — the events are processed in the order they are added.

For example, if you were to reverse the order of the listeners on your "wrapper"  and click on the wrapper *element* (not the button) you would notice the same behavior (bubble would fire first):

```
// 1. "Wrapper Bubble" 2. "Wrapper Capture"
document.getElementById('wrapper').addEventListener('click', function () { console.log('Wrapper bubble'); }, false);
document.getElementById('wrapper').addEventListener('click', function () { console.log('Wrapper capture'); }, true);
```

However, if you were to use the same order (bubble before capture) and click on the `button` the capture will fire before bubble. This is because the "click" event is being triggered on the `button` and is "captured down" through the dom before "bubbling up" (the normal event flow).

I've created a [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/apanij/2/edit) that will hopefully help clarify this (however, it may just add to the confusion). The "ordered" button / div triggers the order of your 1st snippet, and the "unordered" button and div use the order in you 2nd.

For additional info see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11841423/1048479) SO answer and the W3C [Event Flow](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-flow) documentation, specifically the [Target Phase](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#target-phase).

Comment: Curious that they just chose to just ignore any precedence passed along just because "it's on the same element anyway". I can't find the literal text in the spec, but given your explanation and the cross-browser implementations following this behavior, it must be true! Thanks :)