# dispatchEvent produces calls capture/bubble listeners out of order

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, safari, dom-events

When I emulate mouse events with `dispatchEvent`, event listeners are called in an order different than real mouse events. In particular, some *bubble* listeners are called before *capture* listeners on the same target.

Here's a fiddle to illustrate what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/soney/8stNc/2/

In it, I wrote:

```
function logFN(message) {
    return function() {
        console.log(message);
    };
}

var event_type = "click";

addEventListener(event_type, logFN("Capture 1"), true);
addEventListener(event_type, logFN("Bubble  1"), false);
addEventListener(event_type, logFN("Capture 2"), true);
addEventListener(event_type, logFN("Bubble  2"), false);

var ev = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
ev.initMouseEvent(event_type, true, true, window, 
          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
dispatchEvent(ev);
```

With **emulated** mouse events (as produced in the code above), the order is:

```
Capture 1
Bubble  1
Capture 2
Bubble  2
```

With **actual** mouse events, the order is what I expect:

```
Capture 1
Capture 2
Bubble  1
Bubble  2
```

I've tested this in the latest versions of Chrome, Firefox, and Safari. All three browsers produce the same behavior, so it probably isn't a bug. Can anyone explain why the order is different and how to produce the "real" order with emulated events?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The discrepancy wasn't caused by differences between emulated & real mouse events; it was caused by differing event targets.

The "emulated" mouse events I was producing had event targets of `window`. The "real" mouse events I was producing had targets which were more specific than `window`, like `document.body`.

When the event target is the same as the object on which `addEventListener` was called, listeners are called in the order they were added, as explained here: [Event listeners registered for capturing phase not triggered before bubbling - why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11841330/event-order-capturing-bubbling)

For the emulated events, the event target was the same as the object the listeners they were called on, so the capture/bubble distinction didn't matter to JavaScript's event model.

For the real events, the event target was **not** the object the listeners were called on, so the capture/bubble distinction mattered.