# How do dom events propogate in capture and bubble phases?

Tags: javascript, html, events, dom

I'm very confused by this case I wrote. Without further ado, here's the code:

```
<body>
<div id="b">
    <div id='a'>TeTS</div>
</div>
</body>
<script>
    var shitsauce = document.getElementById('a')

    shitsauce.addEventListener("click", function() {
        console.log('a regular 1')
    })
    shitsauce.addEventListener("click", function() {
        console.log('a capture')
    }, true)
    shitsauce.addEventListener("click", function() {
        console.log('a regular 2')
    })
</script>
```

I would have assumed that on click of the element 'a', the order of events would be:

- a capture
- a regular 1
- a regular 2

But instead I'm seeing:

- a regular 1
- a capture
- a regular 2

I thought all capture handlers would always be exeucted before any non-capture handlers. This is the way it's described here: https://javascript.info/tutorial/bubbling-and-capturing . Why isn't that happening in this example?

Comment: From the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener): "*Note: For event listeners attached to the event target; the event is in the target phase, rather than capturing and bubbling phases. Events in the target phase will trigger all listeners on an element regardless of the `useCapture` parameter.*" Use another element inside your `#a` to click on.

Comment: Ahhhh, ok that's what I was thinking might be the case in bed last night lol. You should make that an answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event order capturing/bubbling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11841330/event-order-capturing-bubbling)